# Error when calling PHP class in other file

Tags: php, google-translate

I have this error when I call the `TranslateClient` class:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'TranslateClient' not found in
>   C:\MAMP\htdocs\GoogleTranslate\trans.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\GoogleTranslate\trans.php on line 7

The PHP code is:

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
require_once('TranslateClient.php');
$tr = new  TranslateClient(); // Default is from 'auto' to 'en'
$source->setSource('en'); // Translate from English
$target->setTarget('ka'); // Translate to Georgian
$text ='of course';
 $tr->setUrlBase('http://translate.google.cn/translate_a/single'); // Set Google Translate URL base (This is not necessary, only for some countries)
$var = TranslateClient::translate($source,$target,$text);
echo $var;
 ?>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The `TranslateClient` class is in the `Google\Cloud\Translate` namespace. At the very least, you'll need to add this to your class instantiation, or add a `use` statement. Are you using an autoloader at all? If not, you're likely to run into further problems.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php

Comment: no i'm not used composer for autoloader just fils Tokens and TranslateClient

Comment: you'll likely need to add a `use` statement then, to access the correct namespace. But there's a good chance these classes rely on other Google classes which you also need to include, and pretty soon it'll end up being easier to use the autoloader

Comment: tank you it's work